# ASP.Net Cascading DropDownLists disable on 1 ListItems / enable on 2 or more

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP and web technology- I've designed a cascading dropdownlist of 8 boxes. They all filter upon the prior boxes until you end up with one final selection. I'm wanting to disable the boxes if they have only one result - therefore showing the user that they don't need to select that box to look for an option, but to enable it if there's 2 results or more (since they might go back to a prior box and change the selection) and so they know they need to select something in this box.

I'm able to populate all the boxes automatically, but right now, users have to select each box one by one to ensure there's no other choices - this is something I want to avoid.

Below is a sample of box 5 (DDLCountry). The box before is DDLModel and the next box after will be DDLType.

Any help would be appreciated and I'm always glad for any feedback on improving how this works.

```
        <%-- DropDown County --%>

    <asp:DropDownList id="DDLCountry" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="Country" Height="27px" Width="160px" AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="5">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PartFinderConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Models.Country, [CC Group List].[CC Grouped], Models.Make FROM [CC Group List] CCSort INNER JOIN [CC Group List] ON CCSort.[CC Grouped] = [CC Group List].[CC Grouped] INNER JOIN Models ON [CC Group List].CC = Models.CC WHERE [CC Group List].[CC Grouped] = @DDLCC AND Models.Make = @Make AND Models.Year = @DDLYear AND [Models].[Model Name] = @DDLModel ORDER BY Models.Country ASC;">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLCC" Name="DDLCC" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLMake" Name="Make" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLYear" Name="DDLYear" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLModel" Name="DDLModel" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```